# Executing a batch file from HTML or some other GUI

Tags: html, batch-file

I have a simple batch file sitting in my windows system -
    @echo off
    echo %1 >> %2

This batch file takes two arguments, 1st is a string and second is a filename. It appends the passed string to the file.

Its straightforward to execute this batch file from command line, but I need to execute this from GUI.

Is it possible to execute this batch file from a browser? Can I write a simple HTML file which accepts two arguments and execute this batch file on pressing a button?

Are there any other ways to create a simple GUI for executing this batch file?

Comment: Well yes if you install IE 4 or earlier. Wee bit unsafe your idea isn't it...

Comment: @Tony I agree, allowing browser to execute batch files on local machine is unsafe. But is there a way to white-list my batch file in current browsers, because I know that this batch file is harmless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible to run a command line call from javascript within your webbrowser, this is due to security risks.

You could however use multiple other methods.  If you know any Java you could create a very simple Java program using a Swing interface which makes a call to the command line.  You could also choose to run a php page on your localhost, this would allow you to have a html front end in your browser which sends a request to your server which could then make the call for you.

Comment: I know basic java, but will have to read through Swing. But I like the idea of a java application to create GUI. Thanks.

Comment: Swing is pretty easy especially for what you are trying to do.  The Java code itself will most likley use the Runtime and Process classes.

Comment: I was able to accomplish the task using Swing. Thanks.